# How to set up a Steam profile showcase?

Tags: steam

I noticed some people can create showcase of their Steam objects they want to trade or their in-game screenshots.

**Can someone explain how to set up this ?**

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate? It answers your question but doesn't ask your question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120847/what-do-steam-profile-levels-do

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You unlock the ability to create an extra showcase **every 10 levels**. If your Steam level is lower than 10, you can't have any at all. This info is in the [Trading Cards FAQ](https://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq).

Once you've unlocked a showcase, simply [go to your own Steam profile](https://steamcommunity.com/my) and click the "add a showcase" block with the dashed line around it.

[image: + Add a Showcase]

Comment: Do you happen to know if there was another way to get more showcases? Like for developing badges or something like that. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Once you hit level 10, you can set a featured showcase in your profile settings. You get more showcases as you level up further.

[image: Featured Showcase]