# Can I buy steam games right after I've created a new account and its at level 1?

Tags: steam

I'm wondering if I can buy a game for example PUBG on a newly created acc/account that's still level 1?

Comment: I'm sure they'll take your money as soon as possible.

Comment: The Steam level thingy is almost completely pointless. See https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120847/what-do-steam-profile-levels-do

Comment: The only thing I know that will stop you from buying a game is, if you were banned from said game on your current account (for example if they take your copy of CS:GO away, you won't be able to buy a new one and get access again).

Comment: @JohnHamilton He said "right after I've created a new account"; so it would be pretty hard to already be banned on a game as soon as you make your steam account.

Comment: @JMac - I've seen stranger things, to be honest. O.o

Comment: @JMac If they cared, they could IP ban him or cross-reference the credit card details, but I think Steam sees having to re-buy the game as enough of a deterrent.  Or they're just happy you're willing to throw more money at it.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Oh totally.  I just think he missed the detail about the steam account being new (i.e. not banned from Counter Strike).

Comment: My son was banned on CS:GO. I know for a fact they did not ban him on the second Steam account he had to make, where he re-purchased the game.

Comment: Why would they ever put any sort of barrier in front of you spending money with them?

Comment: @MaxWilliams: Because of the cost/benefit ratio? E.g., in iRacing (online only simracer), it would make sense to ban a paying customer when he ruins every world championship race. Not banning would result in bad publicity and other drivers striking, the latter again resulting in bad publicity. So whether or not someone should be banned depends. Apart from that: Isn't banning one of a user's several accounts exactly what you call a _barrier_?

Comment: @phresnel my mistake, i didn't realise one could be banned from making purchases.

Comment: Usually with the games industry it works the other way around: you spend money to get to a higher level faster. It's all about how the company makes money off of you.

Answer (score 38):

Yes, even level 0 accounts can purchase games.

Comment: There is such a thing as level 0?

Comment: @Mast steam accs are locked to lv0 until you buy 5$'s worth of stuff.

Comment: I guess by definition, you will stay level zero until money is spent.

Comment: There is such a thing as Steam levels?

Comment: @curiousdannii yup, they had been a thing since forever. Buying games or crafting badges give you XP, and you can level up with that, and that increases your max friend count and give you profile slots every 10 levels etc.

Comment: @Ave That was a sarcastic riff off Mast's comment. Though until reading this I had truly forgotten Steam levels were a thing, despite using Steam most days.

Answer (score 10):

Technically you can buy a Steam game without an account, provided that you buy it in a physical store.  That's how I was first introduced to Steam.  Of course you have to create an account to activate the Key that comes with the games, but physical games, like their digital counterparts, have no level requirement.